# Mandatory Coupon code for specific Woocommerce product category items

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy, coupon

In Woocommerce, I'm trying to make a Coupon Code mandatory for all Products from a specific Category.

The following code (placed in functions.php) works well, but makes Coupon Codes mandatory for all Products regardless of the product category:

```
add_action('woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'make_coupon_code');

function make_coupon_code()
{
    global $woocommerce;
    if(is_cart() || is_checkout()){
        $my_coupon = $woocommerce->cart->applied_coupons;
        echo $woocommerce->cart->get_applied_coupons;
        if(empty($my_coupon))
        {
            wc_add_notice( '<strong>' . $btn['label'] . '</strong> ' . __( 'insert coupon code', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

*(the Product Category I'm trying to target is 'chef-masterclass')*

Comment: I would post this to code review stack exchange because you don't have a specific error which we can fix.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec that’s why I suggested code review not Wordpress....

Comment: @LoicTheAztec https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @RyanSchaefer I have never use Codereview StackExchange yet :( lol… Normally for Wordpress related there is mainly 2: StackOverFlow and WordPress StackExchange… So why not Codereview if OP wants to…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated:** The code below will prevent checkout for a mandatory coupon code that need to be applied for a specific product category:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'mandatory_coupon_code' );
function mandatory_coupon_code() {
    // HERE below -- Your settings
    $mandatory_coupon   = 'summer'; // <== Coupon code
    $product_categories = array( 'chef-masterclass' ); // <== Product category (Id, slug or name)

    $applied_coupons = WC()->cart->get_applied_coupons();

    // If coupon is found we exit
    if( in_array( $mandatory_coupon, $applied_coupons ) ) return;

    $found = false;

    // Loop through cart items to check for the product category
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        if( has_term( $product_categories, 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ){
            $found = true; // cart item from the product category is found
            break; // We can stop the loop
        }
    }

    // Coupon not applied and product category found
    if( $found ){
        // Display an error notice preventing checkout
        $coupon_html = '<strong>"' . ucfirst( $mandatory_coupon ) . '"</strong>';
        $message = sprintf( __( 'Please enter the coupon code %s to checkout.', 'woocommerce' ), $coupon_html );
        wc_add_notice( $message, 'error' );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works

Comment: LoicTheAztec, your codes close, but rather than automatically adding the Coupon, I'm trying to get the Coupon entered by the customer (despite the value of the Products under the Category 'chef-masterclass' to be free). The coupons purpose is to just validate their involvement. Bascially I'm trying to say to the customer... Enter the code supplied to you for this Category of Product or you cant purchase it.(despite being free anyway).

Comment: @Crundi I have updated my answer code… It should be convenient this time. You just need to define your coupon code inside the code…

Comment: Firstly thanks for your help on this, however, that seems to have caused the Cart and Checkout to be unreachable. I'm using WooCommerce Version 2.6.7, could that be the issue?

Comment: is there a way to add multiple coupon codes to this PHP?. I tried the below but it didn't work...
    `$mandatory_coupon   = 'summer','Autumn','Winter'; // <== Coupon code`

Comment: I tried to define a few coupon codes that will allow the user to pass through to the checkout... but this didn't seem to work either...
`$mandatory_coupon = array("summer", "Autumn","Winter");`