# Create bulk coupons using smart coupons - but compulsory for products in a certain category

Tags: php, woocommerce, coupon

I am using *"[Get a coupon code dynamically from WooCommerce in a custom function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56138586/get-a-coupon-code-dynamically-from-woocommerce-in-a-custom-function/56139512#56139512)"* answer code,
which ensures that specific products requires a coupon code in order to complete the purchase. Really awesome.

However I also used Woo Smart Coupons to generate coupons in bulk. I notice that even though I select the option "force specific items" this option in not checked in the coupons that are generated.

And thus the checkout doesn't work - when the products require a coupon code. I need to have this option checked.

How can I ensure that this option is checked by default, rather than have it selected when generating?

Comment: The related answer code that you are using is simply not compatible with Woo Smart Coupons third party plugin...