# Woocommerce: Mandatory coupon for specific products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, coupon

Based on [Make coupon field mandatory for a product category in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51723849/make-coupon-field-mandatory-for-a-product-category-in-woocommerce/51725402#51725402) answer, I am trying to implement a mandatory coupons for specific products in woocommerce.

Here is my code attempt:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'mandatory_coupon_for_specific_items' );
function mandatory_coupon_for_specific_items() {
    $targeted_ids = array(40, 41, 42, 43, 44); // The targeted product ids (in this array)
    $coupon_code = 'summer1, summer2, summer3, summer4, summer5'; // The required coupon code

    $coupon_applied = in_array( strtolower($coupon_code), WC()->cart->get_applied_coupons() );

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach(WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        // Check cart item for defined product Ids and applied coupon
        if( in_array( $cart_item['product_id'], $targeted_ids ) && ! $coupon_applied ) {
            wc_clear_notices(); // Clear all other notices
        
            // Avoid checkout displaying an error notice
            wc_add_notice( sprintf( 'The product"%s" requires a coupon for checkout.', $cart_item['data']- 
            >get_name() ), 'error' );
            break; // stop the loop
        }
    }
}
```

The code works perfectly to make a coupon mandatory but I need that ONE fo the products can be checkedout using only ONE of the coupons.

With the actual code if I add product ID 40 to the cart, is obligatory to add the 5 coupons, summer1, summer2, summer3, summer 4 and summer5, otherwise the checkout will be impossible. I would like the customer can make the checkout using any of the coupons for any of the products listed in the targeted_id array.

In other words, for all the products the use of coupon is mandatory but not necessarily a specific coupon, could be anyone of the listed in the code.

For example purposes I listed 5 products and 5 coupons, but in reality there are 100 products and 100 coupons

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some mistakes in your code, use the following instead:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'mandatory_coupon_for_specific_items' );
function mandatory_coupon_for_specific_items() {
    $targeted_ids  = array(40, 41, 42, 43, 44); // The targeted product ids (in this array)
    $coupon_codes  = array('summer1', 'summer2', 'summer3', 'summer4', 'summer5'); // Array of required coupon codes

    $coupons_found = array_intersect( array_filter( array_map( 'sanitize_title', $coupon_codes) ), WC()->cart->get_applied_coupons() );

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach(WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item ) {
        // Check cart item for defined product Ids and applied coupon
        if( in_array( $item['product_id'], $targeted_ids ) && empty($coupons_found) ) {
            wc_clear_notices(); // Clear all other notices

            // Avoid checkout displaying an error notice
            wc_add_notice( sprintf( 'The product"%s" requires a coupon for checkout.', $item['data']->get_name() ), 'error' );
            break; // stop the loop
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: It worked perfectly! Thank you so much @LoicTheAztec